# Change Displayed URL Structure using mod_rewrite NOT Working

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I need to change the structure of the displayed client-side URL.  I'm not too skilled using regex and coding for the .htaccess file.  Basically, I have a structure that looks something like:

```
http://www.example.com/catalog/index.php?cat=lt&sec=lt1-1&id=nmlt10.
```

I would like this to be displayed in the address bar as:

```
http://www.example.com/catalog/lt/lt1-1/nmlt10.
```

This is what I came up with, but it has had no effect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ /catalog/index.php?cat=$1&sec=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

I tested and removed any other rules in the .htaccess file to ensure nothing was being overwritten.  I'm on a shared hosting apache server, and know that mod_rewrite is enabled, because I use it to rewrite  non-www to www urls.  I don't receive and 500 error messages, I just do not notice any change at all.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: 1) Where this .htaccess file is located -- which folder? 2) remove back slash before `$` in your pattern.

Comment: .htaccess is in the root folder...I removed the backslash, but now I get a 500 error.

Comment: 2) Check Apache error log for exact error description as `$` is a special character and mean "end of string". If escaped with back slash then it is just $ character. 1) If .htaccess is in website root folder, then rule will not match -- as URL has 4 segments while your rule have only 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution that worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1&sec=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Appreciate LazyOne's response to get me on the right track; however, when using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&sec=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

I wasn't able to following links that were already placed on the site, it treated different directories as the variables, for example, when browsing to an image or file, say:

```
folder/folder/image.png
```

It would grab "folder" - "folder" - and "image" as the variables.  I can see why that was happening, if anyone has a different solution or an explanation, please let me know, I'm always willing to learn.

Comment: Easy (as long as no aliases/virtual folders are used) -- see my updated answer -- it will check if requested URL is not a file or folder before doing any rewriting. **P.S.** You have not actually explained what problems you had with that rule -- just "it does work and does not work at the same time" is not good for explanation -- details are important.

Answer (score 0):

Since your .htaccess is in website root folder, then you should use thus rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /catalog/index.php?cat=$1&sec=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

If you place it in .htaccess in `/catalog/` folder, then you can remove `catalog` from it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&sec=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

I have tested rule before posting -- works fine for me.

---

This rule (same as above) will check if URL is a file or folder and will only rewrite if it is not:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&sec=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Worked when placed in /catalog/ directory; however, it seems to affect content on the pages.  Would using this rule affect GET variables, because content requiring CERTAIN get variables are not appearing on the page.

Comment: The `QSA` flag should copy all existing query parameters to new URL -- check the [documentation, if necessary](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa). What you can do -- add `,R` after `L` flag -- it will do proper redirect (URL changes in browser) , so you can see how this URL will look like to your scripts.