# change url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a url that looks like

```
mysite.com/index.php/home/user_get
```

which works fine.

however my client now wishes to have a hashbang in the url

```
mysite.com/username
```

Is there anyway to in code igniter allow me to use this type of url whren i logged in?

Comment: that must be done through htaccess

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with Javascript. Removed tag.

Comment: Where's the hashbang? I don't see it :)

Comment: infact, codeigniter has link to that

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

also use this link, asked previously if you get confused

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860757/change-displayed-url-structure-using-mod-rewrite-not-working

Comment: I think its better to make the controller which handles the usernames as default controller..

Answer (score 5):

To get rid of index.php prefix you'll have to enable mod_rewrite in your apache config file and use htaccess to rewrite url.

To enable mod_rewrite, open httpd.conf file and uncomment the following line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

To rewrite URLS you have to place .htaccess file (named exactly '.htaccess') into your site root and add the following lines to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|scripts|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Third line is important, as it allow static content to be served. You'll have to modify it to match your project structure.

Making user-dependent is impossible, I think.
See [mod_rewrite documentation for reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

**UPDATE:** 
If it is just about usning `mysite.com/username` instead of `mysite.com/index.php/home/user_get` you could define `username` controller, with single method

```
public function index(){
    redirect('/home/user_get', 'refresh');
}
```

If you going to support several users, e.g. mysite.com/john, mysite.com/dave, that might help

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|images|scripts|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule $1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(products|categories)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/users/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

this will route any requests to unknown 'controller' to users controller. You'll have to list all your controllers in `(products|categories)`. In the users controller you will have username as parameter, just if your url would be /users/username. Please note that this is not tested.

Comment: the mod-rewrite part to get rid of index.php may be correct but your last line about user-dependence is misinformed and OP wasn't really asking about that. The `/username` is not in the context of mod-rewrite and that part can be dynamic as it's a controller function.

Comment: @efgx that line is not about user-dependent rewrite, but about serving static content. It's form live site, so I'm absolutely sure it correct. As of user-dependent rewrite - I don't even know if it is possible.

Comment: I understand but he wasn't asking about user dependent rewrite or user dependent anything, and by looking at his original posting the code in the line about getting the username is not actually related to what he was talking about at all. It was just an example, and I'm pointing it out because it could have been confusing. NP

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^username$ http://sitename.com/profile/profile.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]       i am use this code for redirect username to the particular user profile page... but i am use statically username .. i want to use dynamically username in RewriteRule ^username$ http://sitename.com/profile/profile.html [NC,L] ... ^username$ instead of dynamic username

Answer (score 0):

How to remove the index.php from the URL is well documented elsewhere.

To handle URLs like `http//domain.com/myusername, http://domain.com/yourusername, http://domain.com/theirusername` then you can do something like this:

```
// in config/routes.php
   $route['home'] = 'index';
   $route['404_override'] = 'user';
```

Other controllers should continue to work normally, but do a bunch of testing to work that part out.

```
// in controllers/user.php
    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) 
    {
        // detail urls can work as well
        // /myusername/posts, /myusername/friends, etc.
        $this->$method();
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->user_home();
    }
}
   function posts() {}
   function friends() {}
   function user_home()
   {
       if($this->uri->segment(2) != FALSE)
       {
           // this is either a 404, or you have a controller missing
           show_404();
       } else {

           $q = $this->db->get('users');
           if($q->num_rows() == 1)
           { 
              // show user info...
           } else {
              // this is IMPORTANT!! 
              show_404();
           }
       }
   }
```

Anyway, that's a starting point for you to work with...(untested code)

Answer (score 0):

I am shocked not one single person has actually responded with a link to the Codeigniter documentation for the Router class. What you want to do is follow the instructions for a custom .htaccess file as [supplied by John above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007041/change-url-in-codeigniter/7007124#7007124).

You only want the following in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|scripts|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The Codeigniter URI Routing documentation can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html). I am presuming by /username you mean you want to be able to redirect different usernames to different pages, to a profile page or something.

In your `application/config/routes.php` file add the following lines:

```
// Insert any other routes you don't want hijacked here

// Example - a contact page.
$route['contact'] = "pages/fetch/contact"; 

$route['(:any)'] = "controller/method/$1";
```

The $1 means capture the value from (:any) and supply it as an argument to your controller function. If you want to be able to link to other sections of the site like a contact page and it just so happens to be located at: /contact - then you'll have conflict issues with the URL location being hijacked.

No need to do anything else, or add anything to any controllers.